# Ionic 4 beta doesn't support crashlytics?

Tags: ionic-framework, crashlytics, ionic-native, ionic4

I’ve created a new ionic app with ionic version 4.0.0-beta.7 and while adding the Crashlytics plugin, my app is not compiling successfully. Also i cannot see the documentation for crashlytics on https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/native/. So do ionic 4 beta supports crashlytics or not?

I am getting the following exception in browser console.

Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at index.js:194
    at Object../node_modules/@ionic-native/fabric/index.js (index.js:296)

My app is using ionic native 5.0.0.beta-15.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ionic 4 is all like before (about plugins), just need to append "/ngx" to the path of the wrapper of the plugin. So if the path was "@ionic-native/crashlytics" now it  "@ionic-native/crashlytics/ngx"

Comment: Tried that but its not working because  "@ionic-native/crashlytics/ngx" is not a valid path for crashlytics.

Comment: You alright, you need to install the beta package. You can install it like so - "npm i @ionic-native/crashlytics@beta"